# X axis yearly labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the following code it is for a yealy line plot.

However the x axis don't show the years.

How is it possible to make it?

```
# Load the required library

    library(ggplot2)
    
    # Create the data as a dataframe
    yearly_evolution_data <- structure(c(`2008` = 1L, `2011` = 4L, `2012` = 4L, `2013` = 20L,
                                         `2014` = 19L, `2015` = 30L, `2016` = 48L, `2017` = 97L,
                                         `2018` = 146L, `2019` = 176L, `2020` = 277L, `2021` = 314L,
                                         `2022` = 392L, `2023` = 353L), dim = 14L,
                                       dimnames = structure(list(c("2008", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014",
                                                                   "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020",
                                                                   "2021", "2022", "2023")), names = ""), class = "table")
    
    # Convert the data to a dataframe and reset row names
    yearly_evolution_df <- as.data.frame(yearly_evolution_data)
    yearly_evolution_df$Year <- as.numeric(rownames(yearly_evolution_df))
    
    # Plot the line time evolution with years for every count and volume number on the line
    ggplot(yearly_evolution_df, aes(x = Year, y = Freq, label = Freq)) +
        geom_line(color = "blue", size = 1.5) +
        geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +
        geom_text(vjust = -1, size = 3) +  # Add text labels for volume numbers
        labs(title = "Yearly Evolution",
             x = "Year",
             y = "Count") +
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = yearly_evolution_df$Year, labels = rownames(yearly_evolution_df))
```

Edit with this code:

```
    # Plot the line time evolution with years for every count and volume number on the line
    ggplot(yearly_evolution_df, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq, label = Freq, group = 1)) +
        geom_line(color = "blue", size = 1.5) +
        geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +
        geom_text(aes(fontface = "bold"), vjust = -1, size = 5) +  # Add text labels with bold font and larger size
        labs(title = "Yearly Evolution",
             x = "Year",
             y = "Count") +
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = yearly_evolution_df$Year, labels = rownames(yearly_evolution_df)) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),  # Rotate x-axis labels for better visibility
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),  # Adjust size and font face for y-axis labels
              axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))  # Adjust size and font face for y-axis title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `Var1` column is a `factor` containing the years you could map `Var1` on `x` and add `group=1` (which means to treat all observations as belonging to one group which we name `1` for simplicity.):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(yearly_evolution_df, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq, label = Freq, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_text(vjust = -1, size = 3) + # Add text labels for volume numbers
  labs(
    title = "Yearly Evolution",
    x = "Year",
    y = "Count"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. please could you take a proposal for the updated code as well what is going wrong?as I made the update with group 1

Comment: Remove the `scale_x_continuous` line (see my code). Should have mentioned that. As `Var1` already contains the years it's no longer needed and as `Var1` is a factor aka a discrete variable will result in an error `discrete variable mapped on continuous scale`.